# Rails adding method, action to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, action

Rails... pretty hard to learn from 0
Im making project about autosop.
1 user makes advertisement, sets, where he is going, and other users can join him.
I have problem adding action, since i just dont know how to make it.
I have made already authorization, autentification.
Where things get tricky - i have 2 scaffolds - Advertisement (user fills form with data). And AdvertisementCommitment(dont even need scaffold imho, but.. ok). In Database - it is user_id and advertisement_id.
At the moment, User can make advertisement.
If i go to /advertisements index page, i get all advertisements listed nicely. I want to add a link to each advertisement  - to commit.

Question - where and what i need to do, to make this action work ? How to pass that advertisement to advertisement_commitment ?

SOLVED

```
<%= link_to "Join", { :controller => 'advertisement_commitments',
  :user_id => current_user.id, :advertisement_id => advertisement.id}, 
  :method => :post %>
```

maybe it will be useful for someone :)

Answer (score -2):

have a look at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

You will then have a better idea of how Rails works, and how you can get Rails to do what you want...